# Measure cube volume without point cloud or depth

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, vector, computer-vision

I would like to compute the volume of that cube in the figure without point cloud or depth map, I don't have access to them, but I have access to the corners of the cube in the screen space coordinates.

I know the ground mesh it's it a 0,0,0. Then I project a ray from origin 0,0,0 to all the points. I'm following the article to project a ray from camera to an image plane http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=363

My question is how would I know which points are candidates for the cube and which points are not candidates ?
[image]

Comment: Can you assume the box is a uniform colour?

Comment: yes, its uniform color